# C# EFCore is not showing tables after adding migration and updateing it

Tags: c#, postgresql, sqlite, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am now working on a project for university where I am trying to extract some data from a database and then send it through rest controllers.

The problem I have is that after I do the first migration and update the database the tables do not appear in the database. Also, tried to seed some data in the table but it still not working.

DatabaseAccess.cs (class that inherits DbContext)

```
using Domain.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EntityDataAccess;

public class DatabaseAccess : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=../EntityDataAccess/sep3db.db");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(
            new User
            {
                Id = 1,
                Email = "alex@gmail.com",
                Password = "1234",
                Role = "Admin",
                Username = "Alex"
            }
        );
        
        // Constraints, Primary keys, Foreign keys, etc.
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(user => user.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(user => user.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().HasKey(recipe => recipe.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().Property(recipe => recipe.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
    
    public DbSet<User>Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Description> Descriptions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }

}
```

User.cs (Model class)

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace Domain.Models;

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }  
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Programs.cs

```
using EntityDataAccess;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseAccess>();


var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I think it is irrelevant anyway. I tried first to generate the database in PostgreSQL.

here:

```
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=../EntityDataAccess/sep3db.db");
```

as, instead:

"Host=localhost; Port=5432; Database=sep3db; Username=postgres; Password=postgres;"
I had the same problem, the tables were not there and this is Why I decided to try SQLite as well.

Thank you in advance!

If you have some good resources, please do not hesitate to share!

P.S: i am a noob so if i made some obvious mistakes or need to add more stuff to detect the problem, just be patient with me :)

- first i added the migration then update
- refreshed the database (i am using the db tool from Rider)
- I tried with and without a constructor in the User model class
- deleted all the other DbSet instead of Users
- cheked with Database Browser for SQLite, the tables still do not show

Comment: get some logs from the output tab

Comment: How did you run the db migration? via package manager console?

Answer (score 0):

I took a step back and started over. Deleted the migrations and the .db file from the project.

So after I did the migrations again and the .db file appeared in the project again i went in the Database tool and added the new source. There i realized that in the choose file field it was not the path of the .db file from the project. I think this is what was wrong in the first place.